# Writing down a two-dimensional function corresponding to the solid one generates by rotating a 1D function about its axis of mirror symmetry

Tags: geometry, functions

Say I have a 1D function like $f_x = cos(x)$ that has reflection symmetry with respect to some axis, here $x = 0$.  Making $f_x$ a Gamma distribution with arbitrary parameters $(k,\theta)$, or a normal distribution with $\mu = 0$ would also work.  Is there a straightforward way to write down some two-dimensional function $g_{(x,y)}$ the corresponds to the solid one would generate by revolving $f_x$ about its axis of mirror symmetry $(x = $ some constant$)$?

Comment: **Don't** use the *same* name for $two$ different functions.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of coordinate vertical axis the formula is simply
$$z=F(x,y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$
Think yourself the changes required for a rotating axis $x=c$ constant.

Comment: @MMartín-Blas Pérez Pinilla For $x = c$ its just $z=F(x,y)=f(\sqrt{(x-c)^2+(y-c)^2})$, no?  Incidentally, what happens if $f_x$ does not have reflectional symmetry about $x = c$?

Comment: Then, the *thing* isn't a function graph.

Comment: Well, you'd have multiple solutions are points in this case, wouldn't you?

Comment: $z=F(x,y)=f(\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2})$ With your formula the rotation axis is the line $x=c$, $y=c$.

Comment: Right, sorry, I see that now.

Comment: In a function, *by definition* there is only a $z$ for each $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me.  What is that "thing" and how can I understand it?

Comment: It certainly does look odd when you plot out solutions for $x = c$ values where this does not correspond to a line of mirror symmetry.